# input field changes url

Tags: html

I am sure this is a basic one.

I am not sure how to describe this but when I press return in an input field it changes the URL to put the input name and value pair in the URL, e.g. for this code :

> ```
> <form name="searchForm">  
> <input name="searchTerm">  
> </form>
> ```

after having typed "fred" in the searchTerm field and pressed return, the URL changes to

test.html?searchTerm=fred

The thing is I have a submit button to do an XMLhhtprequest how do I stop this URL change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle the `submit` event for the form. The easiest (but ugliest) way to do it is this:

```
<form name="searchForm" onsubmit="return false">
```

But since you have Ajax set up (which should be listening to `submit` anyways) use `evt.preventDefault();` or `return false;` there instead. Also remember to only cancel when the request appears to have succeeded!

Comment: At the risk of displaying even more ignorance could you give me a quick ensample of what you mean by ajax listening to submit, I am not quite sure I understand you.

Comment: You have an XMLHttpRequest, right? And I assume you send it in the (on)`submit` event of the form? If you're not, you should - not the `click` event of the submit button, because as you've seen, Return submits the form as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, good stuff, as a closing remark before I slink away any book recommendations for ajax are appreciated.

Comment: Head First Ajax, O'Reilly Books, is a starting point, though it has a couple problems with it. But if you're looking to learn Ajax, it's fairly good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onsubmit` attribute to prevent this:

```
<form name="searchForm" onsubmit="return false;">
```